# Show $\Bbb{R}^2/C \cong \Bbb{T} \times \Bbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $\Bbb{T}$ be the multiplicative subgroup of $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ with unit modulus and $C$ the additive subgroup of $\Bbb{R}^2$ generated by a non-zero vector. Show that $\Bbb{R}^2/C \cong \Bbb{T} \times \Bbb{R}$.

My initial thought is to in some way encorporate the first isomorphism theorem, much like the case of $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z} \cong \Bbb{T}$, but I cannot quite figure it out. So another thought is to come up with some chain of isomorphisms in which each constituent isomorphism would be easier to handle. However, I have been told that there is a 'natural' isomorphism which, of course, would be preferable.

Hints and directions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $q: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{T}$ be the quotient map which you already know. Now you have the sequence of group homomorphisms: $$C \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{q \times \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}}} \mathbb{T} \times \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: So I have been thinking about this for quite some time now, but still do not understand the hint. Would you mind giving me further hints or explain in greater detail?

Comment: Consider the line spanned by the choice of nonzero vector, and decompose $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the direct sum of this line and its orthogonal complement. Then you have the sequence of homomorphisms above, and you just need to verify that $0 \to C \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{q} \mathbb{T} \times \mathbb{R} \to 0$ is a short exact sequence.

Comment: So I have not encountered exact sequences before, but this was a fun exercise. Please tell me if my solution approach is correct. If we let $C$ be generated by say $(v_1,v_2)$, then I chose the injection $f: C \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as 
$f(v) = (\frac{1}{v_1} \mathrm{proj}_x(v), 0)$, (projection onto $x$-axis, if $v_1 = 0$ then $f = 0$ which also is the case that I already know). Then $\mathrm{im}(f) = \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\} = \ker (q\times \mathrm{id}_\mathbb{R})$. This is also a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define a function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{R}$
  by $\varphi((x_{1},x_{2}))=(e^{ix_{1}},x_{2})
  $
  for all $(x_{1},x_{2})\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Find the kernel and then use the isomorphism theorem. This shows that  $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\left\langle v\right\rangle \cong\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{R}$
  for some nonzero $v$. A variation of $\varphi$ can be given to show that $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\left\langle v\right\rangle \cong\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{R}$ for any nonzero $v$.
 .

Comment: I have been staring at the problem for a while, but I cannot quite figure it out. If I let $(v_1,v_2)$ be my generating vector of $C$, then I can come up with $\phi(x_1,x_2) = (e^{i 2 \pi x_1/v_1}, x_2)$ which will give me that $\ker \phi = \langle v_1, 0 \rangle$, i.e. I cannot figure out the second coordinate. I would like the function to be periodic, with period $nv_2$, but I cannot get some periodic function without ruining the homomorphism. Can you help from here?